# calculate 2^n for large N

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to calculate 2^N for large value of N i.e. upto 10^9 with mod operation.
Used an iterative approach but its taking a lot of time for the input 10^8.

`for(long i=1;i<=n;i++){
   res=(res*2)%1000000007
}`

Its taking time in calculating for n=10^8 and above.

Comment: `2^n` is equivalent to `1 << n`. That's `n`-long binary number, which gives us 1 megabyte of data filled with zeros. Well, there's gotta be another way.

Comment: What is the mod supposed to achieve?

Comment: Your algorithm is O(N). Of course it takes along time with large N.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz But he's calculating the modulus at every step, so it never gets to be millions of bits long.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the speed by squaring as well as multiplying by two - e.g. 2^4 can be reached as 2*2 => 4, 4*4 => 16.

Start with 2. If N is even, square what you have and halve N. If N is odd, multiply by two and decrement N. Apply the modulus as you go.

You may have to be careful the squaring doesn't overflow.